# Django get_or_create and ManytoManyField

Tags: python, django

I'm previously used ForeignKey.

Model

```
class Phone_request_list(models.Model):
    who = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    whose = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

View

```
def phone_request(request):
    user_id = request.user.id
    uuid = request.GET.get('uuid')
    profile_id = profiles.objects.get(uuid=uuid).user_id
    p,created = Phone_request_list.objects.get_or_create(who=user_id,whose_id=profile_id)
    p.save()
```

but now I want to change my model to manytomany field

```
class Phone_request_list(models.Model):
    who = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    whose = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

This time how can I check `whose` with `who` in `get_or_create`. Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def phone_request(request):
    user_id = request.user.id
    uuid = request.GET.get('uuid')
    profile_id = profiles.objects.get(uuid=uuid).user_id
    p,created = Photo_request_list.objects.get_or_create(who=user_id)
    p.whose.add(profiles.objects.get(uuid=uuid))
    p.save()
```

btw, you didn't need that final p.save() when you were using a ForeignKey but you do now you have a M2M

Comment: Are you sure about needing to `.save()` after adding to a m2m? I am trying it right now and it doesn't seem like it matters.

Comment: at time of writing I seemed to think so. Perhaps later versions do not require a save